# Crud with React Express Mysql не обновляет компонент

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

Я делаю crud с помощью express, reactjs, mysql. Я написала в бэкэнде './routes/task'

```
    app.put('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {

    let sql = `UPDATE task SET (content) VALUES (
        '${req.body.content}' ) WHERE id = ${req.params.id}
    `;

    database.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                status: 400,
                success: false
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 200,
                success: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

В интерфейсе компонента Task я написала '.src / pages / Task'

```
 const update = async (id) => {
     axios.put('http://localhost:3005/tasks/'+id, {
        content: task
    })
        .then(async (res) => {
            await getList();
        });
}
```

а в return компонента Task у меня есть

```
<Fragment>
    <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>Task</title>
    </Helmet>
    <Container>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                    <Form.Label>Task</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" value={task || ""} onChange={handleChange} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={save}>
                    Post Task!
                </Button>
                <br/><br/>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <h2>Tasks</h2>
                {taskList.length && taskList.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Card key={index} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{moment(item.date_time).format('LLL')}</Card.Subtitle>
                                <Card.Text>{item.content}
                                    <input placeholder={item.content}/>
                                    </Card.Text>

                                <Button variant="danger" size="sm" data-id={item.id} onClick={() => remove(item.id)} >Delete</Button>
                                <Button variant="danger" size="sm" data-id={item.id} onClick={() => update(item.id)} >Update</Button>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    )
                })}
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
</Fragment>
```

Когда я ставлю «Обновить», нужно обновить item.content и заменить его новой строкой, но это просто не работает. Не могли бы вы мне помочь?

Comment: `UPDATE task SET content = '${req.body.content}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`

Comment: Сработало один раз и теперь записывает null вместо значения  которое я вписала в поле